# Adding object to child collection causes entire collection to load in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have my Parent object, which contains an ICollection of Children objects.  The Children are lazy loaded and I do not need them in the context of my scenario.  However, when I try to add a new child object to my Children collection, it kicks off the lazy load and loads all 7000 child records.

I assume I am making a newbie mistake.  Anybody out there know how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the Inverse() call to my mapping, and all is well now.